# Compass App windows

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I am interested in using the Compass app on windows. I bought the product but it comes with absolutely no documentation. (fail)
I have no idea how to use it.

I created a project and got this structure

```
directory compassProject/ 
directory stylesheets/ 
directory project/ 
   create manifest.rb 
   create _main.scss 
   create screen.scss
```

I assume I am to edit a `css` file somewhere and compass will employ `SASS` to rewrite it somewhere else?

Thanks in advance
Teedub

Comment: Well the documentation of compass itself is at [compass-style.org](http://compass-style.org/). How you need to use that app, i don't know, because you don't say which one you use. And personally i think that the command-line is sufficient.

Comment: If you go to the main compass page, at the bottom, there is a section talking about "The Compass App" for windows. It runs on JRuby. I do not have ruby installed. I have searched for several hours for any kind of documentation. The app developer has a youtube with no sound and such poor resolution you cannot see anything that they are doing.

Comment: I don't use the app, but my guess is that you either select the created project from history or select `Watch a folder...` and select the folder containing `manifest.rb` then the app itself will call `compass watch` and then if you change your `screen.scss` it will be instantly compiled into `stylesheets/screen.css`

Comment: Why would you think you edit a CSS file when Compass/Sass is for compiling sass/scss files into CSS?

Comment: I'm sure your compass app would compile your .sass or .scss files into css. When working with compass, you do not need to edit your css. Your compass app would take care generating the css while you are editing sass files.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, you need to install Ruby (required). As of this date, it is recommended that you use the Ruby 1.9.3 installers: RubyInstallers: [Ruby 1.9.3-p550](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/)

Once Ruby is installed, install Compass:

`gem install compass`

For more info on installing Ruby for Windows, refer to this post I have made on this topic:
http://jimfrenette.com/2014/11/compass-on-windows/

**SASS**
Setup sass to compile style.scss automatically
From within your projects sass folder, execute the sass watch command. Whenever your style.scss file is saved, the respective style.css will be written with all of the applicable browser extensions, reusable properties, etc..

```
# change to your sass folder in your project directory
# e.g., cd ~/mywebsite/sass

$ sass --watch  style.scss:../css/style.css
 >>> Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
←[32m      write ../css/style.css
←[0m←[32m      write ../css/style.css.map
←[0m
```

This post details using Bourbon, a similar, lighter Compass alternative which may help if your interested: http://jimfrenette.com/2014/10/bourbon/